# CMake regex match escape characters throw error

Tags: regex, cmake

I have a config file that defines some number of variables:

foo.cfg:

```
NAME    = foo
VERSION = 0.1.0
```

and a cmake file that defines a function that parses said config file and stores the values in variables

parse.cmake:

```
function(parse_config file)
  file(READ ${file} _file_content)

  set(_property "NAME")
  set(_regex "${_property}\s*=\s\K\S+")

  string(REGEX MATCH ${_regex} _name ${_file_content})

  set(_NAME "${_name}")
endfunction()
```

but when I include the script and try to call the function, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error in cmake code at

[... path to "parse.cmake" ...]

when parsing string

${_property}\s*=\s\K\S+

Invalid character escape '\s'.
```

When I use `\\` for the escape characters the regex doesn't find any matches.

Comment: Did you try putting the regex directly in the `string()` call instead to see if that worked? `string(REGEX MATCH "${_property}\s*=\s\K\S+" _name ${_file_content})`

Comment: Yes but unfortunately with the same result

Comment: CMake does not support `\K` operator, it is a PCRE and Onigmo supported construct..

Comment: Sequence ``\s`` has no special meaning for CMake Regex, you may check [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-specification). And `Syntax error` refers to the `set` invocation, not to the `string(REGEX MATCH)` one as implied by the title to your question.